# Show indicator when holding an listitem

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In UWP I can use the right click event on a list item to open a context menu either when I make a right click with the mouse or when I tap and hold the item with my finger. But when I use the touch version, there is no indicator that the context menu is "ready to open" and the menu will just open when you take your finger away.

I tried the holding event in addition to the right click. That works well so far as that the context menu is opened after a second of holding. But then when I take the finger away the right click event fires as well what causes a flickering effect because the context menu is closed and opened at another place again.

The OneNote UWP app for example has this little square who gets bigger so you know that the menu item will open a context menu. Same if you open a context menu on a text box.
How can I add something like that in my own application?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this. I'll look deeper into it and come back to you.

Comment: That would be great.. unfortunately I have no idea how to tackle this issue.. =(

Comment: the right click issue was fixed in anniversary update, so if you set project target version and mini version to build 14393 it will works fine. but for earlier version you may need check if the menu has been opened in both right click and holding event handler before you show the context menu.

Comment: I tried it on build 14393 but I still have the case that holding and right click event are fired. Do I have to do something special?